# django image uploaded section doesnot shows up in production

Tags: django, image, production

I tried to upload image from the admin side in production but it doesn't shows up or stores in static/images but it used to work while working in local.
However my static images are loaded and also those I've saved in development are also showing up but while adding new images it doesn't get added to static files.

My model:

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',null=True,default="avatar.svg")
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('base.urls'))
]

urlpatterns +=static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Gallery .html

```
 {% for gallery in gallerys %}
            <!-- ITEM 1 -->
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
              <div class="box-gallery">
                <a href="{{gallery.image.url}}" title="Gallery #1">
                  <img src="{{gallery.image.url}}" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
                  <div class="project-info">
                    <div class="project-icon">
                      <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
```

Settings.py
here i've uploaded only the required ones

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'base.NewUser'


STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static/")


MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "/static/images")

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

views.py

```
def gallery(request):
    gallerys = Gallery.objects.all()
    context = {'gallerys':gallerys}
    return render(request, 'base/gallery.html',context)
```

am i missing something here?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The way to store images in static folder.

Do this:

**views.py:**

```
 def gallery(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
           form = YourForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
           if form.is_valid():
              handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['image'])
              model_instance = form.save()
              model_instance.save()
           else:
              form = YourForm()
        gallerys = Gallery.objects.all()
        context = {'gallerys':gallerys}
        return render(request, 'base/gallery.html',context)

def handle_uploaded_file(f):  
    with open('static/images/'+f.name, 'wb+') as destination:  
        for chunk in f.chunks():  
            destination.write(chunk)
```

**settings.py:**

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
```

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('base.urls'))
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)+static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This is the way that you can store static files.
I hope this may be get you